# How to keep the background color of disabled Button in Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the global style of the disabled `Button` component from `Material-UI`. But the problem is I am unable to keep the original color scheme of the button.

Consider this button:

```
<Button color="secondary" disabled={isLoading}>Create Account</Button>
```

Now by default `Mui-disabled` would be attached to this button. Whose  `color` and the `background-color` are taken from `theme.palatte.action` property. So this disabled button would be having CSS as:

```
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
box-shadow: none;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
```

But I want my disabled button to maintain its original color ("primary, secondary", "error" etc.) added with an opacity of `0.7`. By default, the cursor events are set to none by MUI.

I tried it using the custom theme but I don't know how to maintain the original color of the button. E.g if the `Button` is `primary` keep the primary color, if the `Button` is `secondary` keep the secondary colors.

```
    MuiButton: {
        styleOverrides: {
            root: {
                textTransform: "none",
                boxShadow: "none",
                "&.Mui-disabled": {
                    // background: "initial",
                    // color: "initial",
                    opacity: .7
                }
            },
        }
    }
```

Of course, I don't want to write a custom code for each code. I can do this even by creating a wrapper around the MUI's button and use that wrapper everywhere in my code.
But I want to do it the MUI way by overriding the theme.

How can I implement a global solution?

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you want? just don't set the `disabledBackground` color in the `palette`:

```
import Button, { buttonClasses } from "@mui/material/Button";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

const defaultTheme = createTheme();
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    action: {
      disabledBackground: "", // don't set the disable background color
      disabled: "white", // set the disable foreground color
    }
  },
  components: {
    MuiButtonBase: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          [`&.${buttonClasses.disabled}`]: {
            opacity: 0.5
          },
          // Fix ButtonGroup disabled styles.
          [`&.${toggleButtonClasses.root}.${buttonClasses.disabled}`]: {
            color: defaultTheme.palette.action.disabled,
            borderColor: defaultTheme.palette.action.disabledBackground
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
```

At the current time I'm writing. There is also other [components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/144Bn.png) that reuses the `disableBackground` property, make sure you take a look and are okay with that too. I display them all in the example below.

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Already tried. This doesn't work. Because empty string is an invalid value so the `Mui-disabled` style would Get applied

Comment: @TheCoder Please have a look at the live example. It works fine in there.

Comment: My bad, I saw your solution on the mobile. and assumed you just set empty string to `&.Mui-disabled`. You are actually changing the `palatte.action` properties. Yes, it works. I am assuming this would change the disabled color of all the components, and not only the Button? And I think I am fine with it.

Comment: @TheCoder Yes. I show you all components affected by that change in the demo, so you can decide if this approach is good enough for you.

Comment: This is perfect only for the 'contained' buttons. If the background color is white then that text of disabled button would not be visible

Comment: @TheCoder I assume you also want both the `text` and `outlined` variant to have the same button color regardless of the state (not gray)?

Comment: disabled state is for each type of button

Comment: @TheCoder I have to create a button wrapper that uses a different theme depend on the variant. You can see in my updated CodeSandbox

Answer (score 2):

With the way that the disabled state is handled in the default styles, I think you need to redefine the default colors within your override in order for it to work.

In the source code you can find how the default colors are defined for the [text](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.0.1/packages/mui-material/src/Button/Button.js#L165), [outlined](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.0.1/packages/mui-material/src/Button/Button.js#L175), and [contained](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.0.1/packages/mui-material/src/Button/Button.js#L179) variants.

The example below demonstrates overriding the disabled styles for all three variants with `opacity: 0.7` by redefining the non-disabled colors within the `"&.Mui-disabled"` style overrides.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { alpha } from "@mui/system";
const defaultTheme = createTheme();
const colors = [
  "inherit",
  "primary",
  "secondary",
  "success",
  "error",
  "info",
  "warning"
];
const containedColorStyles = {};
const textColorStyles = {};
const outlinedColorStyles = {};
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
colors.forEach((color) => {
  containedColorStyles[`&.MuiButton-contained${capitalizeFirstLetter(color)}`] =
    color === "inherit"
      ? {
          backgroundColor: defaultTheme.palette.grey[300],
          color: defaultTheme.palette.getContrastText(
            defaultTheme.palette.grey[300]
          )
        }
      : {
          backgroundColor: defaultTheme.palette[color].main,
          color: defaultTheme.palette[color].contrastText
        };
  textColorStyles[`&.MuiButton-text${capitalizeFirstLetter(color)}`] =
    color === "inherit"
      ? {
          color: "inherit"
        }
      : {
          color: defaultTheme.palette[color].main
        };
  outlinedColorStyles[`&.MuiButton-outlined${capitalizeFirstLetter(color)}`] =
    color === "inherit"
      ? {
          color: "inherit",
          borderColor:
            defaultTheme.palette.mode === "light"
              ? "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23)"
              : "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.23)"
        }
      : {
          color: defaultTheme.palette[color].main,
          borderColor: `${alpha(defaultTheme.palette[color].main, 0.5)}`
        };
});
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          textTransform: "none",
          boxShadow: "none",
          "&.Mui-disabled": {
            ...containedColorStyles,
            ...textColorStyles,
            ...outlinedColorStyles,
            opacity: 0.7
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
export default function ColorButtons() {
  const variants = ["text", "outlined", "contained"];
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {variants.map((variant) => (
        <div key={variant}>
          {capitalizeFirstLetter(variant)} Variant
          <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
            {colors.map((color) => (
              <Button key={color} variant={variant} color={color}>
                {capitalizeFirstLetter(color)}
              </Button>
            ))}
          </Stack>
          Disabled {capitalizeFirstLetter(variant)} Variant
          <Stack direction="row" spacing={2} sx={{ mb: 2 }}>
            {colors.map((color) => (
              <Button key={color} disabled variant={variant} color={color}>
                {capitalizeFirstLetter(color)}
              </Button>
            ))}
          </Stack>
        </div>
      ))}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit ColorButtons override disabled colors]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer Ryan.

Answer (score 0):

I have a nice solution for now.

I use the `ownerState` props to get the color props. Next, I use it in the theme's palette. The following example illustrates how to do this for a `contained` button.

```
let theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    // Your custom palette
  },
});

theme = createTheme(theme, {
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      defaultProps: {
        disableElevation: true
      },
      styleOverrides: {
        root: ({ ownerState }) => ({
          '&.MuiButton-contained.Mui-disabled': {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette[ownerState.color].main,
          }
        }),
      }
    }
  }
});
```